# Giving ssh credentials for salt backend with gitfs in vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack, gitfs

I use vagrant to test my salt configs. On one box I have a vagrant salt master and salt minion and on another box I have a salt minion.

I'm trying to switch over to use gitfs to fetch backend from my **private** repo.

This is my `salt.master_config`:

```
hash_type: sha256
auto_accept: True
roster_file: /srv/salt/roster
fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git

file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/environments/base/files
    - /srv/salt/environments/base/states
    - /srv/salt/users

gitfs_remotes:
  - git@github.com:user/repo.git
    - pubkey: /srv/salt/environments/base/files/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - privkey: /srv/salt/environments/base/files/.ssh/id_rsa
  - https://github.com/salt/users-formula.git
  - https://github.com/salt/openssh-formula.git
```

The other gitfs remotes have worked in the past but the new one does not accept the ssh keys.
When running `sudo salt '*' state.apply` I get:

```
ERROR   ] Error parsing configuration file: /etc/salt/master - mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 16, column 13:
        - pubkey: /srv/salt/environments/base/fi
```

I have also tried using the *Master Options* from the vagrantup prosvisioning doc https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/salt.html and added *master_pub* and *master_key* to my `Vagrantfile`:

```
master.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
      salt.install_master = true
      salt.master_pub = 'id_rsa.pub'
      salt.master_key = 'id_rsa'
      salt.install_type = 'stable'
      salt.master_config = 'master'
      salt.minion_config = 'salt-local'
end
```

But this is to ssh to the vagrant box and not actually used for gitfs.

How do you give ssh credentials for the vagrant config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
gitfs_provider: pygit2
gitfs_pubkey: /srv/salt/path/to/files/ssh/id_rsa.pub
gitfs_privkey: /srv/salt/path/to/files/ssh/id_rsa

gitfs_remotes:
  - git@github.com:user/repo.git
```